Excel HSTACK multiple arrays where an array may be empty
I want to abut multiple dynamically sized tables to each other where any one of the tables may be empty.
For example, say I have the following:

where A3 has the following formula:
=LET(
  a, MAKEARRAY(5, A1, LAMBDA(x,y, "hello")),
  b, MAKEARRAY(5, B1, LAMBDA(x,y, "world")),
  c, MAKEARRAY(5, C1, LAMBDA(x,y, "!")),
  final, HSTACK(a,b,c),
  final
)

What I want is to produce the following, if say, B1 is set to 0:

My attempt starts here
If any of A1, B1, or C1 are set to 0, the MAKEARRAY function results in an #VALUE! error instead of elegantly producing a 0x0 array that HSTACK could ignore...
I tried to make up for this by using IFERROR and creating an empty column when a zero was used. Like so:
=LET(
  a, MAKEARRAY(5, A1, LAMBDA(x,y, "hello")),
  b, MAKEARRAY(5, B1, LAMBDA(x,y, "world")),
  c, MAKEARRAY(5, C1, LAMBDA(x,y, "!")),
  err, MAKEARRAY(5, 1, LAMBDA(x,y, "")),
  final, HSTACK(IFERROR(a, err), IFERROR(b, err), IFERROR(c, err)),
  final
)

which produces produces this:

To get rid of the empty column, I tried this using a BYCOL to create a mask and then FILTER:
=LET(
  a, MAKEARRAY(5, A1, LAMBDA(x,y, "hello")),
  b, MAKEARRAY(5, B1, LAMBDA(x,y, "world")),
  c, MAKEARRAY(5, C1, LAMBDA(x,y, "!")),
  err, MAKEARRAY(5, 1, LAMBDA(x,y, "")),
  stack, HSTACK(IFERROR(a, err), IFERROR(b, err), IFERROR(c, err)),
  col_mask, BYCOL(stack, LAMBDA(col, COUNTBLANK(col)<>5)),
  final, FILTER(stack, col_mask)
  final)

which produces #CALC!. I think this is due to the BYCOL(stack,...) function call.
I think Excel can't handle array of arrays because if I split the BYCOL and FILTER into separate cells, this actually works. For example,

where A10 looks like:
=LET(
  col_mask, BYCOL(A3#, LAMBDA(col, COUNTBLANK(col)<>5)),
  final, FILTER(A3#, col_mask),
  final
)

Is it possible to do this in a single cell without VBA?

Instead of BYCOL(stack, LAMBDA(col, COUNTBLANK(col)<>5)) this use this BYCOL(stack,LAMBDA(α, AND(N(α<>"")))) you need to use AND() and this is similar to use MMULT() as well!!

This is the quick fix to your existing formula:


• Formula used in cell A3
=LET(
     a, MAKEARRAY(5, A1, LAMBDA(x,y, "hello")),
     b, MAKEARRAY(5, B1, LAMBDA(x,y, "world")),
     c, MAKEARRAY(5, C1, LAMBDA(x,y, "!")),
     err, MAKEARRAY(5, 1, LAMBDA(x,y, "")),
     stack, HSTACK(IFERROR(a, err), IFERROR(b, err), IFERROR(c, err)),
     col_mask, BYCOL(stack,LAMBDA(α, AND(N(α<>"")))),
     final, FILTER(stack,col_mask),
     final)


Alternatively, could use the following as well:
=LET(
     ƒx, LAMBDA(α,δ,φ, IFERROR(MAKEARRAY(α, δ, LAMBDA(x,y, φ)),EXPAND("",α,,""))),
     stack, HSTACK(ƒx(5, A1, "Hello"),ƒx(5, B1, "World"),ƒx(5, C1, "!")),
     col_mask, BYCOL(stack, LAMBDA(ε, AND(N(ε<>"")))),
     final, FILTER(stack,col_mask),
     final)


The alternative usage of BYCOL() with MMULT()
MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(stack)),N(stack<>""))


MAKEARRAY() can be excluded as well:
=LET(
     ƒx, LAMBDA(α,δ,φ, IFERROR(IF(SEQUENCE(α,δ)^0,φ),EXPAND("",α,,""))),
     stack, HSTACK(ƒx(5,A1,"Hellow"),ƒx(5,B1,"World"),ƒx(5,C1,"!")),
     col_max, BYCOL(N(stack<>""),AND),
     final, FILTER(stack,col_max),
     final)


Can you elaborate on why I needed to use the AND() to collapse the col_mask LAMBDA when used in A3 but not when it was in a different cell (A10)?

AND() function means here all the columns needs to have a value greater than 1, since we are checking if any of the columns is not equal to blank. using N(stack<>"")

@supernun for A10 its different, the BYCOL() finds A10 as a reference range, while when directly used with an BYCOL(stack,LAMBDA( it is pure array. ! This you will understand once you understand the usage of MMULT() !

@supernun i would suggest you to understand the usage of MMULT() function from this post answer

I simplified my needs down to a single value per table but in a real use-case the LAMBDAs in my original example would be doing something more complicated with the row/column variables passed in. Also each table would be doing different things so your fx definition, while very useful, wouldn't apply to my case.

For anyone else wondering, the real reason came down to what @Mayukh Bhattacharya said regarding the difference between "arrays" and "ranges". Unfortunately, COUNTBLANK requires a range and is unable to take an "array". So the solution is to workaround this issue. The best explanation I found is here https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/uetbc0/understanding_arrays_and_ranges/

@supernun I have already stated you. Why its not working and why it is working when used in different cell. One is array and another is reference range. This should at least help to understand that like COUNTIFS() or any ifs family functions dont work with arrays when entered in the criteria range (this also explains why such functions dont work with closed workbooks and returns #REF! error) but does works when used with INDEX() because works both ways it can be used as reference range as well as an array!

My proposal is to use a formula like this:
=CHOOSEROWS(CHOOSECOLS($A$1:$C$1,
--TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($A$2:$C$2))&",",
$A$2:$C$2)),",",,TRUE)), SEQUENCE($E$2,,1,0))



I'll take the blame for this for not being clearer in my post. The "hello", "world" and "!" were just stand-ins to make the problem easier to parse. In reality those fields are dynamically generated depending on the row and column of the array (which is why I was using MAKEARRAY). Also, creating three tables (a, b, and c) independently and then HSTACKing them is much easier to parse as a reader. It reads a bit more like a database join operation
